# Como retornar letras entre pontos usando uma expressão regular?

Tags: regex, google-drive-api

Estou usando o Google Drive e gostaria de utilizar uma expressão regular para separar os caracteres entre pontos, como abaixo :

> a·bai·xa·men·to
> a·bai·xo

Preciso colocar em cada coluna, o conteúdo entre os pontos (no primeiro e último caso só antes e depois do ponto).

> a·bai·xa·men·to => a bai xa men to
>
> a·bai·xo        => a bai xo

Eu precisaria de um código para cada coluna da "resposta" Por exemplo a·bai·xa·men·to (a) primeira letra antes do ponto (b)letra entre os primeiros 2 pontos (c) letra entre o segundo e o terceiro ponto etc.

Comment: Nao diz que linguagem quer usar (para alem de mencionar RegEx), mas assumindo C# por exemplo, pode simplesmente separar a string por pontos `"a·bai·xa·men·to".Split('.') \\ retorna um array de strings`.

Comment: Ah , foi mal. Eu tô usando o google drive. Queria colocar a expressão regular dentro da fórmula  já disponibilizada. Tipo este exemplo abaixo.

a-pedido (nome masculino)
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3;"^[^()]*")
a-pedido

No caso preciso de um comando para cada coluna onde ira retornar as palavras entre os pontos(imagino 8 ou 9). 



Valeu!!

Comment: Precisa de regex? Tu pode ir em Menu -> Data -> Split Text Into Columns (ai escolhe o separador), ou usa a funcao `=SPLIT(coluna, ".")`

Answer (score 1):

Utilize simplesmente `[^\.]+`

Esta regex irá pegar tudo que não for ponto.

No entanto o que você sugere para enumerar cada grupo de caracteres não é possível, pois regex não consegue "contar".

No máximo você consegue pegar o primeiro grupo com `^[^\.]+` e o último com `[^\.]+$`.

De resto sugiro que faça um programa que vá consumindo a string a cada ponto e contando, é bem facinho.

Comment: Não precisa escapar o `.` se estiver dentro de um conjunto de caracteres `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sou expert com expressões regulares, mas acredito que a expressão ficaria assim:

```
[a-z]
```

Comment: Não deu certo, :(

Eu precisaria de um código para cada coluna da "resposta"
Por exemplo a·bai·xa·men·to

(a) primeira letra antes do ponto
(b)letra entre os primeiros 2 pontos
(c) letra entre o segundo e o terceiro ponto
etc..